# JDK6 libraries - compatibility with JDK7

Tags: backwards-compatibility, java-7, jdk6

Is JDK7 backward compatible with JDK 6? Specifically, if I have some jars compiled using JDK6, will I able to use them while developing in JDK7?

Answer (score 3):

> Is JDK7 backward compatible with JDK 6?

- Read [official document](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/compatibility-417013.html#jdk7) about incompatibilities between JDK 6 and 7
- Look at [this table](http://abi-laboratory.pro/java/tracker/timeline/jre/) for independent analysis of API changes. The backward binary and source compatibility of Jre classes between 6 and 7 versions is estimated at 95%:

[image]

...

[image]

The report is generated by the *[japi-compliance-checker](https://github.com/lvc/japi-compliance-checker)* tool.

Answer (score 1):

You'll be able to use class files from previous JREs/JDKs. Compatibility forwards is supported. However you won't be able to go backwards (e.g. JDK7 to an earlier JRE/JDK). The class file format for JDK7 has changed to reflect such things as `invokedynamic`.

Some more in-depth information [discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6699347/jdk-7-class-file-backward-compatibility-with-jdk-6).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can certainly use older .jar files and .class files in your current development with newer compilers :)