# How to use library compiled with jdk7 in jdk6?

Tags: java, java-7, backwards-compatibility, java-6

I am using `android-support-v7` library in my project, but the official libray is compiled with jdk7 and my company must use jdk6.

how can I make the official libray backward jdk6?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17466882/how-can-i-use-a-library-compiled-for-java-7-in-java-6

Answer (score 0):

The library is compiled with jdk 7 , meaning it must be using new features (Example:- `try-with-resources`) introduced in java 7. Hence if somehow you recompiled it in java 6, it will give you compilation errors.

The only way I see is to use jdk 7 in your project if you want to use this library, or search for older versions of library compiled in jdk 6 and use those.