# Version compatibility issues?

Tags: java, apache, ofbiz, opentaps

I'm new to opentaps environment. I have some doubt in opentaps. I have opentaps1.5 version. It is contain apache 6.0.26 and ofbiz 10 version. I want to work using jdk1.8. While compile the program using jdk1.6 or 1.7 it is providing  expected results. When I used jdk1.8 It showing

> ExceptionInInitializerError.

Please tell me how to resolve this issue. I need to work opentaps1.5 with jdk1.8. Thanking you in Advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JDK 7 class file backward compatibility with JDK 6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6699347/jdk-7-class-file-backward-compatibility-with-jdk-6)

Comment: Hi @chandu, Thanks for your information, I'm having problem using jdk1.8 only when I changed jdk 1.6 or 1.7 it is working good.

Answer (score 1):

Apache OFBiz, which is the base of opentaps, just introduced Java 1.8 compatibility in the upcoming 14.12 branch. OFBiz 10 is very old and not maintained anymore. It is not compatible with Java 1.8.

As far as I know, opentaps is forked from OFBiz and might have newer versions which are Java 1.8 compatible.

You may want to contact the support (http://www.opentaps.org/services-support) to get more accurate informations.

Comment: Thank you @MichaelBrohi. It is helpful to me. But I need Opentaps1.5 and jdk1.8. I know that apache and ofbiz version through wiki so i could not known what versions are there in opentaps1.5. Sorry for above. Please let me the compatibility between opentaps1.5 and jdk1.8. Thanks again